# Pandas Regression Model Replacing Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, replace, regression

I have a data frame "df" with columns "bedrooms", "bathrooms", "sqft_living", and "sqft_lot".

[image: Data frame "df"]

I want to create a regression model by filling the missing column values based on the values of the other columns. The missing value would be determined by observing the other columns and making a prediction based on the other column values.

As an example, the sqft_living column is missing in row 12. To determine this, the count for the bedrooms, bathrooms, and sqft_lot would be considered to make a prediction on the missing value.

Is there any way to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This question itself is actually quite loaded because there is quite a bit of consideration that is required in the process of building, processing and evaluating a model. But for simplicity of it, you would first need to drop the rows with missing data, and then use something like sklearn's `linear_model_LinearRegression`. You would train a model using `sqft_living` as your y, and the remaining as x, and then do a `model.predict` on the rows you are trying to get the missing data for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# setup
dictionary = {'bedrooms': [3,3,2,4,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,3,3],
              'bathrooms': [1,2.25,1,3,2,4.5,2.25,1.5,1,2.5,2.5,1,1,1.75],
              'sqft_living': [1180, 2570,770,1960,1680,5420,1715,1060,1780,1890,'',1160,'',1370],
              'sqft_lot': [5650,7242,10000,5000,8080,101930,6819,9711,7470,6560,9796,6000,19901,9680]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

# setup x and y for training
# drop data with empty row
clean_df = df[df['sqft_living'] != '']
# separate variables into my x and y
x = clean_df.iloc[:, [0,1,3]].values
y = clean_df['sqft_living'].values

# fit my model
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(x, y)

# get the rows I am trying to do my prediction on
predict_x = df[df['sqft_living'] == ''].iloc[:, [0,1,3]].values

# perform my prediction
lm.predict(predict_x)
# I get values 1964.983 for row 10, and 1567.068 row row 12
```

It should be noted that you're asking about imputation. I suggest reading and understanding other methods, trade offs, and when to do it.

Edit: Putting Code back into DataFrame:

```
# Get index of missing data
missing_index = df[df['sqft_living'] == ''].index
# Replace
df.loc[missing_index, 'sqft_living'] = lm.predict(predict_x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand the steps you took to get this, but how do I fill in all missing entries in the data frame with the new values? Would it be something like `df['sqft_living'] = lm.predict(predict_x)` ?

Comment: Yeah, that is very close. You would actually need to find fill in the values that are empty. Instead of `df['sqft_living']` it would be something like `df[df['sqft_living'] == '']['sqft_living']`. Does that make sense? You'll need to filter for the rows that are empty and then replace them.

Comment: Do you mean `df[df['sqft_living'] == '']['sqft_living'] = lm.predict(predict_x)` ?

Comment: @c200402 See my edit.

Comment: I am getting an error message: `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

Comment: This is a basic Python data type error, check the outputs for your `lm.predict(predict_x)` and make sure they fit the criteria for a `dtype('float64')`

Comment: All of the outputs are numerical. How do I confirm the outputs fit the criteria?